# Return a string

Tags: prolog

Is it possible to return a string in `prolog`? It yes how may I do that?
I'll pass a name as parameter and I'd like to know what is the time that person is works, I tried this:
This returns me `true`.

```
work_at(sara) :- friday at 9.  
time(X) :- work_at(X).
```

This gives me error.

```
work_at(sara) :- "friday at 9".  
time(X) :- work_at(X).
```

If I want to know the time that someone works, like:

```
time(sara).
```

I'd like to know what day/time sara works.

Comment: You really should read some introductory Prolog tutorial or user guide material. What you're trying to do isn't valid Prolog and isn't how Prolog works at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible to return a string in prolog?

Prolog doesn't work that way. It's not possible to *return* a value. What is possible is to say that some *fact* is *true* for some arbitrary objects from a knowledge base. Fortunately, there are many awesome books covering these subjects right in the beginning (i.e. **Learn Prolog Now**). Probably, it worths to dig in and understand what Prolog is really about.

> I'd like to know what day/time sara works.

There should be some knowledge base and some predicate matching worker and it's working time.

`Sara.pl` file.

```
worker(Sara).
work_at(Sara, "Friday at 9").
```

`worker` is a fact says that there is a `worker` Sara. I.e. there could be another worker Adam, and `worker(Adam)` would extend these knowledge base of all the workers.

`work_at` is a fact defining relation between Sara and her worktime defined as a string.

This file could be loaded in `swipl` session.

```
?- [sara].
% sara compiled 0.00 sec, 1 clauses
true.
```

After that let's find a time when Sara has been working at.

```
?- work_at(Sara, Time).
Time = [70, 114, 105, 100, 97, 121, 32, 97, 116|...].
```

Prolog said that there is a known time, but it's a String, how here is your list of Chars.

With a little bit of `writef` magic this could be deciphered.

```
?- work_at(Sara, Time), writef("%s", [Time]).
Friday at 9
Time = [70, 114, 105, 100, 97, 121, 32, 97, 116|...].
```

And also `Time`'s listing as a list of Chars could be suppressed.

```
?- work_at(Sara, Time), writef("%s", [Time]), false.
Friday at 9
false.
```